# How to solve 2nd order linear diff. eq. with logarithm on the RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if it is actually possible to find a particular solution to the following equation
$$ \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} - u =\ln t$$

I made an attempt by varying constants of the homogeneous equation's general solution but was not able to solve a final integral.

Could someone help on this question? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the special function Ei$(x)$ named "Exponential Integral" ? Without it you can't write the solution on closed form.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about those special functions

Comment: About the function Ei$(x)$, for example see : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html . For general information about the special functions : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales . In any case, you can express the special function as an infinite series, or alternatively on the form of defined integral which closed form is the special function (That is to say a function defined by an integral).

Answer (score 2):

By using [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) we find a particular solution of the form
$$u(t)=A(t)e^t+B(t)e^{-t}$$
where, unfortunately, functions $A$ and $B$ are not elementary: 
$$\begin{cases}
A'(t)e^t+B'(t)e^{-t}=0\\
A'(t)e^t-B'(t)e^{-t}=\ln(t)
\end{cases}\implies 
\begin{cases}
2A'(t)=e^{-t}\ln(t)\\
2B'(t)=-e^{t}\ln(t)
\end{cases}$$
and therefore
$$2A(t)=\int e^{-t}\ln(t)dt=-e^{-t}\ln(t)+\int \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$
and 
$$2B(t)=\int e^{t}\ln(t)dt=e^{t}\ln(t)-\int \frac{e^{t}}{t}\,dt$$
which are related to the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\text{Ei}(t)$ (see also [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(t)%20-%20y(t)%20%3D%20ln%20t)).